# Using VST-plugin effects with .NET framework

Tags: .net, vst

There are numerous so called "VST-plugin" effects available on the internet.

These VST effects can be used to manipulate audio.

I would like to know if there's a way to use the VST plugins with the .NET framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is!
https://github.com/obiwanjacobi/vst.net

It supports implementing plugins in a .NET langauge that will run in unmanaged/native hosts (DAW) as well as hosting (loading) unmanaged/native plugins in a .NET application.

Marc (author of VST.NET)

Comment: A great starting point would be vst.net-master\Source3\Code\Jacobi.Vst3.sln I overlooked that at first.I then tried using the Jacobi.Vst3.TestApp. However, I got the compiler error "Include pluginterfaces/base/conststringtable.cpp" couldn't be opened. No such file or directory. What should I do now?

Comment: I was hoping there might be a simple WinForms sample application that I might just fire up to test it.

Comment: Do not use anything from Source3. It was an attempt to support VST 3.x that failed.

Answer (score 0):

Despite the warning not to use anything from Source3, it is easy enough to get it to compile, but sure enough my DAW did not want to load it.

I was able to fix the compiler error include "pluginterfaces/base/conststringtable.cpp"
by downloading Audio VST3 SDK
https://new.steinberg.net/developers/

Then change C++/Cli project Debug and Release project settings individually to include the path.  But like the author of the repo says, it won't work.